# angular 5+ implement smart-app-banner vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, smart-app-banner

I am trying to use **[smart-app-banner](https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner)** in my app, but since there are no typings on the web for it, I don't know how to use it within angular.

So far I've got this in my **app.component.ts** :

```
import * as smartBanner from "smart-app-banner";
let smartBannerInstance = smartBanner();

constructor() {
    new smartBannerInstance({
        daysHidden: 10, // days to hide banner after close button is clicked (defaults to 15)
        daysReminder: 20, // days to hide banner after "VIEW" button is clicked (defaults to 90)
        // appStoreLanguage: 'us', // language code for the App Store (defaults to user's browser language)
        title: "Title",
        author: "Authot",
        button: "VIEW",
        store: {
            ios: "On the App Store",
            android: "In Google Play"
        },
        price: {
            ios: "FREE",
            android: "FREE"
        }
        // force: 'android' // Uncomment for platform emulation
    });
}
```

But I get the usual

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'options' of undefined at SmartBanner`

How can I make this work?

Comment: depending how that module is bundled, you might need to `import smartBanner from "smart-app-banner";` instead of `import * ..`

Comment: it is not a module, it is a plain vanilla js file, doing the thing you have said, i get `Uncaught TypeError: smart_app_banner_1.default is not a function
    at eval`

Comment: oh I see... but i just realized you are doing `let smartBannerInstance = smartBanner();` then `new smartBannerInstance({` .. shouldn't it just be `new smartBanner({ ... })` ?

Comment: Same - `Uncaught TypeError: smart_app_banner_1.default is not a function
    at eval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the whole deal with implementing a simple JS library into an Angular application goes like this (in this specific case that is, but it will work for most libraries):

First, we import the library by using the all selector as follows:

```
import * as SmartBanner from "../../node_modules/smart-app-banner/dist/smart-app-banner.js";
```

Then, we declare it inside our **AppComponent** class and then we initialize it within the constructor.

```
SmartBanner: any;

constructor() {
    new SmartBanner({
        daysHidden: 10, // days to hide banner after close button is clicked (defaults to 15)
        daysReminder: 20, // days to hide banner after "VIEW" button is clicked (defaults to 90)
        // appStoreLanguage: 'us', // language code for the App Store (defaults to user's browser language)
        title: "Title",
        author: "Author",
        button: "VIEW",
        store: {
            ios: "On the App Store",
            android: "In Google Play"
        },
        price: {
            ios: "FREE",
            android: "FREE"
        }
        // force: 'android' // Uncomment for platform emulation
    });
}
```

And it works perfectly.

If this is somewhat of a performance issue, please anyone that has further knowledge, let me know.

Comment: I implemented like this and getting error TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: Have you installed the plugin as follows: `npm install --save smart-app-banner` ?

Comment: of course. It working well with windows, there is an error on android